# How to generate an excel file and save it to database as a file

Tags: python, django

I have created a function that creates an excel file using xlwt. I was able to download it as file but I want it to be saved to the database first and what I did does not work.

Here's what I did so far.

```
import xlwt

response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="excel-file.xls"'

wb = xlwt.Worbook()
# some excel file generating code here
wb.save(response)

return response
```

After generating the excel file, I tried it to save it to the database but doing this does not work.
(Code below)

```
# file = models.FileField
Reports.objects.create(
   file=wb
)
```

I have also tried saving it to a stream first but saving it like this also does not work.
(Code below)

```
f = io.StringIO()
wb.save(f)

# file = models.FileField
Reports.objects.create(
   file=f
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work".  Also, please be specific about whether your question is about creating an excel file or about saving it to a database.

Comment: @StephenC It's about creating an excel file that can be saved to a database

Comment: Well you have the answer in your question then.  You have shown us code that creates an excel file that *can be* saved to a database!   Please be clear and specific about what you are asking.  Don't leave us having to read your mind about what your real problem is.

Comment: @StephenC No it does not work. That's the problem. The generated excel file can't be saved to a database.

Comment: *"No it does not work. That's the problem."* - WHAT doesn't work?  HOW doesn't it work?  If you want help, you need to explain what your problem is.

Comment: @StephenC Yes it isn't. It's about saving it. Saving it like in the second code block like how you normally save a file to a database does not work. Now what I want is for it to be saved.

Comment: Put this into your question.  If you want a clear answer, you need to write a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I understand what you are asking now.

Unfortunately, the `FileField` class is designed to save an (uploaded) file in the file system, not the database.  This is probably a good thing.  Databases are not designed to be used as file systems.  But either way, if you use `FileField` the database will only contain the file name, not the file content.

So my first suggestion is to use `FileField` and `FileSystemStorage` as intended.  There is some example code in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/#file-storage that shows how to save some stuff into the default file storage.

Alternatively, if you really want to store your Excel object in the database, then you need to change the `FileField` to a `BinaryField`.  Then you can do something like this:

```
  buffer = BytesIO()
  wb.save(buffer)
  // excel = models.BinaryField()
  Reports.object.create(excel=buffer.getValue(), ...)
```

(There are probably more efficient ways to do this.)